# Power solution for Raspberry Pi robot

Tags: motor, raspberry-pi, power

I am building a Pi car with 4 gear motors (190-250mAh each max). Now I want to use my 10000mAh USB power bank to power up raspberry pi along with the 4 gear motors.

I can power up the raspberry pi directly but I want to use my power bank as the only source of power for the Pi Car. How can I connect both my RPi and motor controller L298N to my USB power bank?

Comment: I believe you mean 190 - 250 mA each not mAh.

Comment: Yes you are correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually in your exact situation, and have decided to do the following:

I got a power bank with *two USB outputs*. I intend to connect the first output directly into the raspberry Pi, and then connect the second output to a breadboard to power the motors.

```
              USB 1 -> Raspberry pi
             / 
   Power Bank
             \
              USB 2 -> Breadboard -> Motors
```

However, if my power bank just had *one USB output*, I would have connected it to the breadboard and powered the pi from there as well (through the 5V pin on the PI, I believe):

```
                                     Raspberry Pi
                                    /
    Power Bank -> USB -> Breadboard
                                    \
                                     Motors
```

**PS: Remember to connect the grounds**

In order to connect the USB to the breadboard, I will either cut open an old USB cable and solder the power wires to the board from directly, or look online for something premade that does this neatly for me.

**PPS: I haven't tested this yet, so do it at your own risk :)**

Comment: Yes i already thought about your second option. but the problem is 5V GPIO output pins has no over voltage protection. If i do something messy this could break the pi.

Do you have any suggestions on this? I mean is there any way to protect the GPIO's using diod, fuse or something?

Comment: You are right about the lack of protection with this solution. It is probably possible to add some protection, but I don't currently have a solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use:

1. Two separate voltage sources with ground connected (5V PSU from powerbank + LiPo battery for engines)

or

2. One bigger LiPo battery with 5V regulator circuit for logic.

But if You want to use your powerbank as only energy source, **yes**, it is possible. However:

- Take care of proper decoupling of 5V line. I mean, check datasheet of bridge you want to use, search for recommended connection schematic and use same capacitors, or at least close to them, as described.
- In order to protect your Raspberry from overvoltage, use [Zener diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode), reverse polarized, rated at 5.3V. It should short-circuit supply voltage line at voltages exceeding its nominal value. It shouldn't happen, since your powerbank has already voltage regulator, but if you want to connect H-Bridge with it, I recommend using it.
- Also, I'd recommend You to use different H-bridge, like TB6612FNG. It is capable of powering engines up to 13.5V at 1.6A per channel. It is also smaller and more energy efficient than L298N.

Answer (score 0):

Use a split USB cable.  Something like this should work.

https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/split-microb-usb-power-cable

You might need a breakout board to run your motors if your motor driver can't take a USB source directly for power.